# ld: library not found for -lLIBRARY_NAME, only when trying to build using jenkins

Tags: xcode, jenkins

I have a project that when built from my machine everything runs smoothly. However, when I push my changes and try to generate the build using jenkins, I'm getting the library not found error message.

This is weird because if I login into the jenkins server and I try to do a manual build, everything works as expected, perfect. It's only when I build from withing jenkins that my build is failing.

I'm assuming LIBRARY_NAME as the name of whatever library, in my case is an internal static library.

Any suggestions?

EDIT:

I've setup: Library Search Headers, Other Linker Flags, Target Dependencies, Proper Architectures

Comment: Dump and compare the environment before the build. By the way, does Jenkins runs under the same user as you use for login to the server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrestled with this for three weeks until I accidentally stumbled onto this with the help of a coworker.  Basically, you must be sure that the path structure created in your repository is replicated in the .jenkins workspace.  To do this just be sure that in your project/job configuration in jenkins the Source Code Management > Subversion > Repository URL field must be at the same level as specified in jenkins in your script or Build > Execute Shell > Command field.  So here are my settings as an example: 
above Jenkins URL = https://myDuncwa.local/duncwa-repo
above Jenkins Build = "cd $WORKSPACE/mobileapps/projects/PictureBoard/trunk/PictureBoard" and line 2 "xcodebuild -project PictureBoard.xcodeproj" no quotes.
above Subversion URL repository = https://myDuncwa.local/duncwa-repo 
This will cause the directory structure mobileapps/projects/PictureBoard in my repository to replicated in the .jenkins/jobs/PictureBoard/workspace/mobileapps/projects/PictureBoard directory that is created automatically by jenkins.  Note: 1) This will copy the entire repository so be prepared to change this later and 2) .jenkins is a hidden directory created by the install in the installing user's home directory or "~/"